# Adding VPC endpoint interfaces to NLB target group in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc, nlb, vpc-endpoint

I want to create a VPC in a specified region say (eu-central-1) with a given CIDR say (10.0.0.0/21).
For each available AZ in that region, I want to create a private subnet with a CIDR calculated based on the main VPC CIDR.
Each of these private subnets should host one or more VPC Endpoint Interfaces, depending on how many are specified in the endpoints map.
I want to create an NLB (Network Load Balancer) for each entry in the endpoints map. This NLB's target group should contain the IPs of the corresponding VPC Endpoint Interfaces.
Finally, an Endpoint Service should be created for each NLB, matching the entries in the endpoints map.
So, in essence, each entry in the endpoints map leads to a distinct set of VPC Endpoint Interfaces, a corresponding NLB with a target group that includes those interfaces, and an Endpoint Service pointing to that NLB.

and below is my terraform code:

```
this is main.tf:
module "vpc" {
  source              = "./modules/vpc"
  environment         = var.ENVIRONMENT
  vpc_cidr            = var.vpc_cidr
  private_subnet_cidr = local.subnet_cidr
  subnet_az           = data.aws_availability_zones.az.names
  endpoints           = var.endpoints
  nlb_name          = "NLB"
  target_group_name = "NLB-TG"
}

these are the variables i pass (endpoints variable is of focus here as it would be needed ahead)

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR for VPC to be deployed"
  type        = string
  default ="20.0.0.0/21"
}

variable "aws_region" {
  description = "AWS region to deploy resources in"
  type        = string
  default = "eu-central-1"
}

variable "endpoints" {
  description = "Details for endpoint creation"
  type = map(object({
    service_name = string
    suffix       = string
    dns_name     = string
  }))
  default = {
    "first" = {
      service_name = "com.amazonaws.vpce.eu-central-1.service_name"
      suffix       = "custom"
      dns_name     = "customtest.endpoints.test.trusted.key.in"
    },
    "second": {
      "service_name" : "com2......",
      "suffix" : "main2",
      "dns_name" : "accountid2main2.endpoints.test2.trusted.sxk.in"
    }
  }
}

and finally my vpc.tf file inside the modules folder:

data "aws_region" "current" {}

locals {
  eni_keys = [
    for k, v in aws_vpc_endpoint.vpc_endpoint_interface : [
      for i, eni_id in v.network_interface_ids : {
        key = "${k}-${i}"
        eni = eni_id
      }
    ]
  ]
}
#above locals is something like this
#[
#{ key = "endpoint1-0", eni = "eni-abc" },
#{ key = "endpoint1-1", eni = "eni-def" },
#{ key = "endpoint2-0", eni = "eni-xyz" }
#]

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    "Name"                    =  "vpc-${var.environment}"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
}

resource "aws_default_security_group" "default" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    "Name"                    = "sg-vpc_default"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets_zone" {
  count             = length(var.private_subnet_cidr) > 0 ? length(var.private_subnet_cidr) : 0
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = element(var.private_subnet_cidr, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.subnet_az, count.index)
  tags = {
    "Name"                    =  "subnet-private-${element(var.subnet_az, count.index)}-${var.environment}"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table" {
  count  = length(var.private_subnet_cidr) > 0 ? length(var.private_subnet_cidr) : 0
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    "Name"                    =  "rt-private-${element(var.subnet_az, count.index)}-${var.environment}"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_rt_assoc" {
  count          = length(var.private_subnet_cidr) > 0 ? length(var.private_subnet_cidr) : 0
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.private_subnets_zone.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = element(aws_route_table.private_route_table.*.id, count.index)
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
  description = "Security group for all vpc endpoints"
  vpc_id      =  aws_vpc.vpc.id
  name        =  "sg-vpc_endpoint"

  tags = {
    "Name"                    =  "sg-vpc_endpoint"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
  lifecycle  {
    create_before_destroy=true
 }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group_service" {
  description = "Security group for Services to access all vpc endpoints"
  vpc_id      =  aws_vpc.vpc.id
  name        =  "sg-vpc_endpoint-access"

  tags = {
    "Name"                    =  "sg-vpc_endpoint-access"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
  lifecycle  {
    create_before_destroy=true
 }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "security_group_rule" {
  type                       =  "ingress"
  from_port                  =  443
  to_port                    =  443
  protocol                   =  "tcp"
  description                =  "Allow traffic from sg-vpc_endpoint-access security group"
  source_security_group_id   =  aws_security_group.security_group_service.id
  security_group_id          =  aws_security_group.security_group.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "security_group_rule_service_sg" {
  type                       =  "egress"
  from_port                  =  443
  to_port                    =  443
  protocol                   =  "tcp"
  description                =  "Allow traffic to interface vpc endpoints"
  source_security_group_id   =  aws_security_group.security_group.id
  security_group_id          =  aws_security_group.security_group_service.id
}


resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "vpc_endpoint_interface" {
  for_each = var.endpoints
  vpc_id              =   aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name        =   each.value.service_name
  vpc_endpoint_type   =  "Interface"
  security_group_ids  =  [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
  depends_on          =  [aws_security_group.security_group]
  private_dns_enabled =  true
  subnet_ids          =  aws_subnet.private_subnets_zone.*.id
  tags = {
    "Name"                    = "${each.value.service_name}-interface-${data.aws_region.current.name}-${var.environment}"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner 
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification 
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type 
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
}

data "aws_network_interface" "vpc_endpoint_nics" {
  for_each = { for item in flatten(local.eni_keys) : item.key => item }
  id = each.value.eni
}

#above data is something like this
#("eni-abc", "eni-def", "eni-xyz")

resource "aws_lb" "customer_nlb" {
  for_each = var.endpoints
  name               = "${each.key}-${var.nlb_name}"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets            = aws_subnet.private_subnets_zone.*.id
  # enable_deletion_protection = true
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group" "customer_target_group" {
  for_each = var.endpoints
  name        = "${each.key}-${var.target_group_name}"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  protocol    = "TCP"
  port        = "443"
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    enabled             = true
    interval            = 30
    path                = "/"
    port                = "traffic-port"
    healthy_threshold   = 5
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 10
    protocol            = "HTTPS"
    matcher             = "200-399"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "customer_nlb_listener" {
  for_each = var.endpoints
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.customer_nlb[each.key].arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.customer_target_group[each.key].arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "customer_target_group_attachment" {
  for_each = { for item in flatten(local.eni_keys) : item.key => item }
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.customer_target_group[element(split("-", each.key), 0)].arn
  target_id        = data.aws_network_interface.vpc_endpoint_nics[each.key].private_ip
  port             = 443
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "endpoint_service" {
  for_each                   = var.endpoints
  acceptance_required        = false
  private_dns_name           = each.value.dns_name
  network_load_balancer_arns = [aws_lb.customer_nlb[each.key].arn]
  tags = {
    "Name"                    =  "vpc-endpoint-service-${var.environment}"
    "owner"                   =   var.owner
    "environment"             =   var.environment
    "data:classification" =   var.classification
    "iac-type"            =   var.iac_type
    "iac-stack-name"      =   var.stack_name
  }
}
```

So the problem is when i run terraform plan or apply it gives me this error
Plan: 22 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
╷
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on modules\vpc\vpc.tf line 160, in data "aws_network_interface" "vpc_endpoint_nics":
│  160:   for_each = { for item in flatten(local.eni_keys) : item.key => item }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.eni_keys is tuple with 1 element
│
│ The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.
│
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map keys statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only in the map values.
│
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.

but if comment out locals, data and target_group_attachment part and deploy the infra
and then in 2nd apply uncomment above items it then adds vpc endpoint interfaces to NLb target groups

How can i have this solution completely deployed with single terraform plan or apply

keeping the main requirement such that:

each entry in the endpoints map leads to a distinct set of VPC Endpoint Interfaces, a corresponding NLB with a target group that includes those interfaces, and an Endpoint Service pointing to that NLB.

Answer (score 0):

> but if comment out locals, data and target_group_attachment part and deploy the infra and then in 2nd apply uncomment above items it then adds vpc endpoint interfaces to NLb target groups

That's exactly what you should be doing if you want to keep your current code. And this is the correct solution to your problem.

> How can i have this solution completely deployed with single terraform plan or apply

Its not possible, without fully changing your code-based and architecture. The error clearly states that your for_each depends on values that "cannot be determined until apply". In TF, everything **must be known at plan time**.

Comment: if i may know what changes can be made to make it work?
as it should work in single apply as this code will be called as a module and 2 apply stages isn't an option